# Neo4j: Failed to instantiate BatchInserter

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I encountered the following error when I tried to create a org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserter

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Misaligned file size 68 for DynamicArrayStore[fileName:neostore.nodestore.db.labels, blockSize:60], expected version length 25
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.AbstractDynamicStore.verifyFileSizeAndTruncate(AbstractDynamicStore.java:265)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.loadStorage(CommonAbstractStore.java:230)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.CommonAbstractStore.<init>(CommonAbstractStore.java:118)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.AbstractDynamicStore.<init>(AbstractDynamicStore.java:92)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.DynamicArrayStore.<init>(DynamicArrayStore.java:64)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNodeStore(StoreFactory.java:328)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNodeStore(StoreFactory.java:317)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:161)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.<init>(BatchInserterImpl.java:262)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:87)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:81)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserters.inserter(BatchInserters.java:56)
    at nl.aegon.maintenance.config.MainConfiguration.getBatchInserter(MainConfiguration.java:137)
    at nl.aegon.maintenance.config.MainConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a40c43d.CGLIB$getBatchInserter$6(<generated>)
    at nl.aegon.maintenance.config.MainConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a40c43d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1b2b386e.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:309)
    at nl.aegon.maintenance.config.MainConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a40c43d.getBatchInserter(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 62 more
```

Below you can find the snippet of my Java Configuration class

```
private static class configurationSettings extends HashMap<String, String> {
    {
      put("dump_configuration", "false");
      put("cache_type", "none");
      put("use_memory_mapped_buffers", "true");
      put("neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys.mapped_memory", "5M");
      put("neostore.propertystore.db.index.mapped_memory", "5M");
      put("neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory", "200M");
      put("neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory", "500M");
      put("neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory", "200M");
      put("neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory", "200M");
    }
  }

@Bean
  public BatchInserter getBatchInserter() {
    LOG.debug("Initialising a batch inserter with store directory: {}", databaseConnectionProperties.getStoreDirectory());
    return BatchInserters.inserter(databaseConnectionProperties.getStoreDirectory(), new configurationSettings());
  }
```

What should be the right set of configuration properties to get past this error? I'm trying to bulk import in parallel, 3 files of 64 MB each

I referred to the following in git hub
https://github.com/jexp/batch-import/blob/2.2/sample/batch.properties

Here's the relevant method from Neo4j that's throwing the exception

```
/**
     * Note: This method runs before the file has been mapped by the page cache, and therefore needs to
     * operate on the store files directly. This method is called by constructors.
     */
@Override
    protected void verifyFileSizeAndTruncate() throws IOException
    {
        int expectedVersionLength = UTF8.encode( buildTypeDescriptorAndVersion( getTypeDescriptor() ) ).length;
        long fileSize = getFileChannel().size();
        if ( (fileSize - expectedVersionLength) % blockSize != 0 )
        {
            setStoreNotOk( new IllegalStateException(
                    "Misaligned file size " + fileSize + " for " + this + ", expected version length " +
                    expectedVersionLength ) );
        }
        if ( getStoreOk() )
        {
            getFileChannel().truncate( fileSize - expectedVersionLength );
        }
    }
```

I'm using java 8, SDN4 and neo4j 2.2.5 on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config options are outdated,

for mmio only use `dbms.pagecache.memory=1500M`

The batch-inserter is single threaded, you can't use it in a multi-threaded environment.

How much data do you want to insert?

Have you looked into the [neo4j-import](http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-import-csv/#_super_fast_batch_importer_for_huge_datasets) tool?

The underlying API of the highly concurrent initial parallel-batch-inserter can also used directly but it's not easy to use.

If you **really know** what you're doing, check out this: https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-dataset-import

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael!

Answer (score 1):

Problem might be that you're trying to start a BatchInserter on an existing store that wasn't cleanly shut down. Is that it?

Comment: No, that's not my case actually.

Answer (score 1):

I found that booting up, and then shutting down, a normal `neo4j` server with that `storeDir` fixed this.

I think it's caused by failing to call `BatchInserter.shutdown()` on a previous run.